# Simple expandable table

Tags: jquery, html-table, expandable

I have a simple table that is set to expand hidden tr on clicking an arrow, problem is everything I click in the visible row makes the hidden tr appear. I only need this hidden tr to expand on clicking only the arrow.

Here is my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#report tr:first-child").show();

        $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
            $(this).next("tr").toggle();
            $(this).find(".arrows").toggleClass("up");
        });
        //$("#report").jExpand();
    });
```

and here is my table:

```
<table id="report">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="arrows"></div></td>
        <td class="title">Verify Business Name Availabilty</td>
        <td style="width: 190px;"><img src="images/green-arrow-check.png" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe; width: 190px;"><img src="images/white-arrow-check.png" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe; width: 190px;"><label><input type="radio" name="modifiers[107]" value="106" /> $99 (yearly)</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="arrows"></td>
        <td class="information">
            Ulciscor ut commoveo iriure praemitto vero praesent, iriure ratis aliquip mauris eu causa. Paulatim, patria jugis damnum sed luptatum, bene iustum. Transverbero obruo eligo letatio occuro, pala, demoveo autem velit inhibeo, usitas.   
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe; width: 190px;"></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe; width: 190px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="arrows"></div></td>
        <td>Prepare Incorporation Documents</td>
        <td><img src="images/green-arrow-check.png" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe;"><img src="images/white-arrow-check.png" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe;"><img src="images/white-arrow-check.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="arrows"></td>
        <td class="information">
            Ulciscor ut commoveo iriure praemitto vero praesent, iriure ratis aliquip mauris eu causa. Paulatim, patria jugis damnum sed luptatum, bene iustum. Transverbero obruo eligo letatio occuro, pala, demoveo autem velit inhibeo, usitas.   
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe; width: 190px;"></td>
        <td style="background-color: #bebebe; width: 190px;"></td>
    </tr></table>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ekagil/edit#javascript,html,live)*

use `td:eq(1)` to be more specific about the trigger element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#report tr:first-child").show();

  $("#report tr.odd td:eq(1)").click(function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').next("tr").toggle();
            $(this).closest('tr').find(".arrows").toggleClass("up");
        });
        //$("#report").jExpand();
    });
```

And make sure to use: `$(this).closest('tr').next("tr").toggle();` to find back the right selector in the tree.

Comment: Well that was an easy fix! It's always the little things haha.

Comment: @user1516081 I agree! Happy coding